# How to distinguish between manual and programmatic node expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, extjs

In `Ext.tree.Panel` I can access its TreeView and listen to this event: `afteritemexpand`. However, I need to distinguish between the node being expanded programmatically (e.g. when the node's `expanded` field is set to `true`, and the node gets loaded from the server), and manually (when the user clicks the "+" sign). Namely, I would like to be able to only react to the manual expansion. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the TreePanel has an [itemclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-itemclick) event. Does that work for you?